# Oauth+Java Servlets+OAuthSigner+Servlet class instantiation error

Tags: servlets, oauth, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

> ```
> >     HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class msch.OAuth
> >     
> >     type Exception report
> >     
> >     message Error instantiating servlet class msch.OAuth
> >     
> >     description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
> >     
> >     exception
> >     
> >     javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class msch.OAuth
> >         org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> >         org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
> >         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
> >         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
> >         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
> >         java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> >     
> >     root cause
> >     
> >     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/authn/oauth/OAuthSigner
> >         java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
> >         java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
> >         java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
> >         java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
> >         java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
> >         org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> >         org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
> >         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
> >         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
> >         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
> >         java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> >     
> >     root cause
> >     
> >     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdata.client.authn.oauth.OAuthSigner
> >         org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
> >         org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
> >         java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
> >         java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
> >         java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
> >         java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
> >         java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
> >         org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> >         org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
> >         org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
> >               org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
> >         org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
> >         java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> ```

note: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.36 logs.

The following is the error when I am trying to run my servlet for requesting an Oauth token.
Here msch.OAuth is the servlet class. Do I have to configure the build path and include that class?If so, how? As it is in a folder and there is just a .java file.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling around I found this workaround which solved the problem. I made some changes to the run configuration of the tomcat server. Added the libraries to that as I couldn't find a proper run configuration for my Servlet web application from the ones given.Anyways,it worked!

Comment: If somebody knows please share which run configuration to use for Java Servlet web application.